# Getting strange closure error in plugin

Tags: gradle

I can't understand why im getting closure errors with this plugin.  Take this apply:

```
class MetadataPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    Project project
    MetadataExtension extension

    static final METADATA_REPORT = 'metadataReport'
    static final METADATA_REPORT_TASK = ':' + METADATA_REPORT

    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        this.project = project

        // Create and install the extension object
        extension = project.extensions.create('metadata', MetadataExtension)


        // *** create the tasks ***
        def ignore = project.tasks.create(METADATA_REPORT, MetadataReportTask)
        ignore.group = PLUGIN_GROUP
        ignore.description = 'Gets the detailed information for this project and formats it into a user readable report'

        // *** validate the build file ***
        project.afterEvaluate {

            def String ext_hash = project.extensions.metadata.project_hash

            def String hash = {
                if (ext_hash == null) {
                    throw new InvalidUserDataException(
                            "You must configure the metadata:project_hash value before running any form of build"
                    )
                }
                return ext_hash
            }
            throw new InvalidUserDataException(hash)
        }
    }
}
```

add to it this build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'metadata'
}
metadata {
    project_hash '123123123'
}
```

and it produces this error.

```
19:44:49.934 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
19:44:49.935 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
19:44:49.935 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
19:44:49.935 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] A problem occurred configuring root project 'junit9025097301225311002'.
19:44:49.935 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > com.devops.gradle.metadata.MetadataPlugin$_apply_closure1$_closure2@5bff38f7
19:44:49.935 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
```

I do not understand why the error isn't 123123123 as it should, why is it giving me that apply closure error?  the extension is nothing but a simple pojo.

Answer (score 0):

*project_hash* is a variable so you have to assign the value directly:

```
metadata {
    project_hash = '123123123'
}
```

You are currently using this as a function (like **project_hash('xyz')**) which is not applicable there

Comment: devops.gradle.metadata.MetadataPlugin$_apply_closure1$_closure2@341f9e4

error didn't change

Comment: the big thing is, i understand the closure needs to be run, but i can't understand why it isn't run by the time the afterEvaluate executes